# Center a glyphicon in a bootstrap button when font size is changed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm trying to vertically and horizontally center a glyphicon with an increased font size inside of a Twitter Bootstrap v3 xs button. The icon is too high up and too far to the left. I've tried `vertical-align: middle` and `text-align: center` to no avail.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.glyphicon, .fas, .fa, .fab, .far, .fal {
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tk5u6sng/10/)

Edit: To be clear, the issue occurs with the font size of 15.

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue in the fiddle by increasing the font size, it's always centered. https://jsfiddle.net/tk5u6sng/16/

Comment: On my Mac in Chrome with your 198px example the pause icon is 75px from the left edge of the button and 108px from the right, and 65px on the top and 42px on the bottom. Slightly different numbers on Chrome on Windows but similar.

Comment: Interestingly, if I select the "text" of the button, I can see that the font bounding box extends past the bottom of the button.  By enough that the glyph would be at least close to vertically centred.  I haven't taken a look at the font definition, but maybe there's a problem with the button not allocating space for the full font box if there's no descender height?